# sizeof continues to return 4 instead of actual size

Tags: c++, sizeof

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Do you need to encrypt or decrypt?" << endl;
    string message;
    getline(cin, message);

    int letter2number;

    for (int place = 1; place < sizeof(message); place++)
    {
        letter2number = static_cast<int>(message[place]);
        cout << letter2number << endl;
    }
}
```

Examples of problem: I type fifteen letters but only four integers are printed. I type seven letters but only four integers are printed.

The loop only occurs four times on my computer, not the number of characters in the string.

This is the only problem I am having with it, so if you see other errors, please don't tell me. (It is more fun that way.)

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 11):

`sizeof` returns the size of an expression. For you, that's a `std::string` and for your implementation of `std::string`, that's four. (Probably a pointer to the buffer, internally.)

But you see, that buffer is only pointed to by the string, it has no effect on the size of the `std::string` itself. You want `message.size()` for that, which gives you the size of the string being pointed to by that buffer pointer.

As the `string`'s contents change, what that buffer pointer points to changes, but the pointer itself is always the same size.

---

Consider the following:

```
struct foo
{
    int bar;
};
```

At this point, `sizeof(foo)` is known; it's a compile-time constant. It's the size of an `int` along with any additional [padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Data_Structure_Padding) the compiler might add.

You can let `bar` take on any value you want, and the size stays the same because what `bar`'s value is has nothing to do with the type and size of `bar` itself.

Answer (score 5):

You want to use `message.size()` not `sizeof(message)`.

`sizeof` just gives the number of bytes in the data type or expression.  You want the number of characters stored in the string which is given by calling `size()`

Also indexing starts at 0, notice I changed from 1 to 0 below.

```
for (int place = 0; place < message.size(); place++)
{
    letter2number = static_cast<int>(message[place]);
    cout << letter2number << endl;
}
```

Any pointer on an x86 system is only 4 bytes.  Even if it is pointing to the first element of an array on the heap which contains 100 elements.

Example:

```
char * p = new char[5000];
assert(sizeof(p) == 4);
```

Wrapping `p` in a `class` or `struct` will give you the same result assuming no padding.

Comment: +1. Nice example with p and sizeof(p).  Simpler than my answer.

Comment: @tony: I was just thinking your example was better than mine.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

```
class string
{
    char * ptr;
    //...
    size_t size();  // return number of chars (until null) in buffer pointed to by ptr
};

sizeof(message) == sizeof(string) == sizeof(ptr) == 4; // size of the struct

message.size() == number of characters in the message...
```

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(type)` returns the size of the type, not the object. Use the length() method to find the length of the string.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    cout << "Do you need to encrypt or decrypt?" << endl;
    string message;
    getline(cin, message);

    int letter2number;

    for (int place = 0; place < message.size(); place++)
    {
        letter2number = static_cast<int>(message[place]);
        cout << letter2number << endl;
    }


    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just posting code without explanation if what the problem is is rarely helpful.