# C++ dynamic array sizing problem

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

The basic pseudo code looks like this:

```
void myFunction()
{

int size = 10;

int * MyArray;

MyArray = new int[size];

cout << size << endl;

cout << sizeof(MyArray) << endl;

}
```

The first cout returns 10, as expected, while the second cout returns 4.

Anyone have an explanation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`MyArray` is only a pointer, which on your system, has a size of four bytes.

When you dynamically create an array, you need to keep track of the size yourself.

If you created an automatic array or static array,

```
int MyArray[10];
```

then `sizeof(MyArray)` would be 40.  As soon as the array decays to a pointer, though, e.g. when you pass it to a function, the size information is lost.

Answer (score 2):

[Related to a recent question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570329/sizeof-continues-to-return-4-instead-of-actual-size)

A pointer is a pointer, regardless of what it points *at*. You have to keep track of the size yourself. Better is to use a `std::vector`.

---

`sizeof` returns the size of an expression, which in this case is the size of the type `int*`. This always has the same size, regardless of its value.

For comparison, consider:

```
int i = 0;
i = 23434634;
```

No matter what value `i` takes on, the size of `i` itself is still only `sizeof(i) == sizeof(int)`. A pointer is the same, it just holds a different kind of value.

Answer (score 0):

`MyArray` is of type `int*`. `sizeof()` when called on a variable returns the size of the type of that variable.

While there is a special case for arrays, it's only for stack arrays (i.e. `int MyArray[3];`).

Answer (score 0):

`MyArray` is an `int*`, and `sizeof(int*)` on your system is 4.

`MyArray` is *not* an array.  It is a pointer that happens to point to a block of memory in which you allocated an array.

```
int MyArray[10];
cout << sizeof(MyArray) << endl;
```

That should print 40, which is how big 10 `int`s happens to be on your system.  In this case, `MyArray` *is* an array.  So the size of the type includes the size of all the elements of the array.

`MyArray` in this second case will decay into a pointer, but they are still two distinct types.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

#define P(expr) std::cout << #expr << " = " << (expr) << std::endl

namespace {
  void myFunction(size_t size) {
    int *pointer = new int[size]; 
    int MyArray[size];

    P(size);
    P(sizeof(MyArray));
    P(sizeof(pointer));

    delete [] pointer;    
  }
}
int main() {
  myFunction(10);
}
```

Output:

```
size = 10
sizeof(MyArray) = 40
sizeof(pointer) = 8
```

Comment: Its worth pointing out that your definition of `MyArray` is a non-standard extension.